# VirtualHost ServerAlias working for some but not others. mod_rewrite related?

Tags: apache, dns, virtualhost

I'd like 4 URLs to end up in the same place. I'm using ServerAlias settings in my virtualhost config to accomplish it. For 2 ServerAlias entries, it works, but not for the third. Here are the URLs that should end up in the same place:

- libbyh.com
- www.libbyh.com
- libbyhemphill.com
- www.libbyhemphill.com

My libbyh.com virtualhost files looks like so:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName libbyh.com
ServerAlias www.libbyh.com www.libbyhemphill.com libbyhemphill.com
ServerAdmin libbyh@gmail.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/libbyh.com
DirectoryIndex index.php
<Directory /var/www/html/libbyh.com/>
  AllowOverride All
  Order Deny,Allow
  Allow from all
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

The rewrite-related bits of .htaccess:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

libbyhemphill.com and www.libbyhemphill.com both end up in the right place, but www.libbyh.com returns 404s. I can't find anything in the logs that tells me why. I tried `dig` for www.libbyh.com and get the DNS settings I expected, but `ping` fails. What's up? Where else can I look? I changed both DNS nameservers and moved the site to a new server on Thursday (now Saturday). I added A records for www.libbyh.com and libbyh.com on the new nameservers. Is there a DNS setting I screwed up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

libbyh.com, libbyhemphill.com, and www.libbyhemphill.com  all have 216.47.`158`.239 whereas www.libbyh.com has 216.47.`156`.239

Are you sure your DNS is correct for www.libbyh.com?

Comment: Thank you! Had A entries at both the old and new nameservers, and one was wrong.